# PHP Imagick bezier connect start and finish point and don't start at pos 0,0

Tags: php, imagick, bezier

I have tried to create some bezier's with Imagick in PHP.
Until so far it works, my only problem is how can I start the bezier at some other point (not at 0,0)  and connect the start and finish points?
any help is appreciated :)

This is the code i'am using:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(500, 500, 'none', 'png');

$bezier1 = new ImagickDraw();
$bezier1->setFillColor('#B42AAF');
$bezier1->setStrokeColor('black');
$bezier1->setStrokeWidth(1);

$bezier2 = new ImagickDraw();
$bezier2->setFillColor('FB9407');
$bezier2->setStrokeColor('black');
$bezier2->setStrokeWidth(1);

$coordinates_1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x] => 250
            [y] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x] => 394
            [y] => 166
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [x] => 316
            [y] => 288
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [x] => 250
            [y] => 324
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [x] => 163
            [y] => 299
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [x] => 163
            [y] => 200
        )
)

$coordinates_2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x] => 250
            [y] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x] => 437
            [y] => 141
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [x] => 410
            [y] => 342
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [x] => 250
            [y] => 405
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [x] => 169
            [y] => 296
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [x] => 101
            [y] => 164
        )
)

$bezier1->pathStart();
$bezier2->pathStart();

for($i = 0; $i < count($coordinates_1); $i++)
{
    $bezier1->pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothAbsolute($coordinates_1[$i]['x'], $coordinates_1[$i]['y']);
    $bezier2->pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothAbsolute($coordinates_2[$i]['x'], $coordinates_2[$i]['y']);
}

$bezier1->pathClose();
$bezier2->pathClose();

$image->drawImage($bezier1);
$image->drawImage($bezier2);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

1e result is for showing points (with polygon):

[image: Polygon]

2e result is the bezier problem (top-left pos 0,0):

[image: Bezier]

3e result is with using pathMoveToAbsolute to try and move the "pencil" to the starting position. Which fails even harder :(

[failed bezier http://downloads.gdwebs.nl/failed-bezier.png](http://downloads.gdwebs.nl/failed-bezier.png)

Comment: BTW, you have a typo in `$bezier2->pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothAbsolute` second param (possible copy-paste issue.) I think it might affect the whole process.

Comment: first tell the path to move to point "wherever" so you're not on (0,0), then inject your curve parameters.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Do you know the command for this? I tried it with pathmovetoabsolute which result in the bezier being broken.

Comment: @mudasobwa This is just a piece of the code I made a rewrite of the code to show you guys only the problem, as you can see the array is  also incorrect (I used a print_r) :P

Comment: for each outlinne the procedure would be moveto, then bezier + outline, then *finalize* if the API requires this (it might. if it does and you don't call it, things get really weird!), then starting a new shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there does seem to be a problem with the function for which I [have opened an issue](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues/57), I don't think this function is going to do what you are hoping it would do, assuming that you want a smooth outline.

Basically there is not enough information being given in that function to produce a smooth outline.

In particular:

- The first line drawn will always start as a completely straight line, as pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothAbsolute assumes the first two Bezier control points are co-incident for the first line.
- There will be a discontinuity between at least the last co-ordinate you're drawing and the joining bit back to the first point. I think there may also be discontinuities between every point, as there just isn't enough information to draw smooth curves.

I think what you need to do is:

- Calculate the tangent vector for each point that you're drawing.
- Scale that by the 'value' of each point aka the distance from the chart's centre.
- Also scale it by how rounded you want the chart.
- Use that as the basis for drawing bezier curves with DrawPathCurveToAbsolute.

Below is a quite rough code example. The input values are just the radius in a polar co-ordinate system, and the points are drawn with equal angle between them.  It has two ways of drawing the shape, either with a bezier curve as described above, or by interpolating the values around the angles (which produces a very 'round' graph, and then interpolating that with a straight line version....the code may make more sense than that description.

Anyway some example images produced are :

Bezier

[image]

Curvy interpolated

[image]

Less curvy interpolated

[image]

```
<?php


define('debug', false);


$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(500, 500, 'white', 'png');


function interpolate($fraction, $value1, $value2) {
    return ((1 - $fraction) * $value1) + ($fraction * $value2);
}

function interpolateArray($fraction, $curvedPosition, $linearPosition) {

    $result = [];

    for ($i=0 ; $i<count($curvedPosition) ; $i++) {
        $result[$i] = interpolate($fraction, $curvedPosition[$i], $linearPosition[$i]);
    }

    return $result;
}


class SpiderChart {

    /**
     * @var \ImagickDraw
     */
    private $draw;

    private $chartWidth = 500;
    private $chartHeight = 500;

    private $segments = 100;

    function __construct() {
        $draw = new ImagickDraw();
        $draw->setFillColor('#B42AAF');
        $draw->setStrokeColor('black');
        $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);

        $this->draw = $draw;
    }

    /**
     * @return ImagickDraw
     */
    public function getDraw() {
        return $this->draw;
    }

    function drawChartBackground() {
        $this->draw->line(
            25, 
            $this->chartHeight / 2,
            $this->chartWidth - 25,
            $this->chartHeight / 2
        );

        $this->draw->line(
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            25,
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight - 25
        );

        $this->draw->setFillColor('none');

        $this->draw->circle(
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight / 2,
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight / 2 + 200 
        );

        $this->draw->circle(
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight / 2,
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight / 2 + 100
        );
    }


    public function getInterpolatedPosition($p, $i, $points) {
        $angleBetweenPoints = 2 * M_PI / count($points);
        $fraction = $i / $this->segments;
        $angle = ($p + ($fraction)) * $angleBetweenPoints;
        $firstValue = $points[$p];
        $secondValue = $points[($p + 1) % count($points)];
        $averageValue = interpolate($fraction, $firstValue, $secondValue);

        $positionX = sin($angle) * $averageValue ;
        $positionY = -cos($angle) * $averageValue ;

        if (debug) {
            echo "angle $angle positionX $positionX, positionY $positionY \n";
        }

        return [$positionX, $positionY];
    }

    public function getLinearPosition($p, $i, $points) {
        $angleBetweenPoints = 2 * M_PI / count($points);
        $fraction = $i / $this->segments;
        $startAngle = $p * $angleBetweenPoints;
        $endAngle = ($p + 1) * $angleBetweenPoints;

        $startPositionX = sin($startAngle) * $points[$p];
        $startPositionY = -cos($startAngle) * $points[$p];

        $endPositionX = sin($endAngle) * $points[($p + 1)];
        $endPositionY = -cos($endAngle) * $points[($p + 1) % count($points)];

        return [
            interpolate($fraction, $startPositionX, $endPositionX),
            interpolate($fraction, $startPositionY, $endPositionY),
        ];
    }


    public function drawBlendedChart($points, $curveLinearBlend) {
        $this->draw->setFillColor('#B42AAF9F');
        $this->draw->translate(
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight / 2
        );

        $this->draw->pathStart();

        list($nextPositionX, $nextPositionY) = $this->getInterpolatedPosition(0, 0, $points);

        $this->draw->pathMoveToAbsolute(
            $nextPositionX,
            $nextPositionY
        );

        for ($p=0 ; $p<count($points) ; $p++) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->segments; $i++) {
                $curvedPosition = $this->getInterpolatedPosition($p, $i, $points);
                $linearPosition = $this->getLinearPosition($p, $i, $points);

                list($nextPositionX,$nextPositionY) = interpolateArray(
                    $curveLinearBlend,
                    $curvedPosition,
                    $linearPosition
                );

                $this->draw->pathLineToAbsolute(
                    $nextPositionX,
                    $nextPositionY
                );
            }
        }

        $this->draw->pathClose();
        $this->draw->pathFinish();
    }


    /**
     * @param $points
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPointTangents($points) {
        $angleBetweenPoints = 2 * M_PI / count($points);
        $tangents = [];

        for ($i=0; $i<count($points) ; $i++) {
            $angle = ($i * $angleBetweenPoints) + M_PI_2;

            $unitX = sin($angle);
            $unitY = -cos($angle);
            $tangents[] = [$unitX, $unitY];
        }

        return $tangents;
    }

    /**
     * @param $points
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPointPositions($points) {
        $angleBetweenPoints = 2 * M_PI / count($points);
        $positions = [];

        for ($i=0; $i<count($points) ; $i++) {
            $angle = ($i * $angleBetweenPoints);

            $positions[] = [
                sin($angle) * $points[$i],
                -cos($angle) * $points[$i] 
            ];
        }

        return $positions;
    }

    /**
     * @param $position
     * @param $tangent
     * @param $direction - which sign the control point should use to multiple the unit vector 
     * @return array
     */
    private function getControlPoint($position, $tangent, $direction, $roundness) {

        //TODO - this scale needs to be done properly. The factors should be
        // i) the value of the current point.
        // ii) The curviness desired - done
        // iii) The cosine exterior angle.


        // top-tip - the interior angles sum to 180, so exterior is (180 - 180/n)
        // for an n-sided polygon

        $scale = 60 * $roundness;

        $resultX = $position[0] + $direction * $tangent[0] * $scale;
        $resultY = $position[1] + $direction * $tangent[1] * $scale;

        return [$resultX, $resultY];
    }


    function drawBezierChart($points, $roundness) {

        //Calculate the tangent vector for each point that you're drawing.
        $tangents = $this->getPointTangents($points);
        $positions = $this->getPointPositions($points);

        $numberOfPoints = count($points);

        $this->draw->setFillColor('#B42AAF9F');   

        $this->draw->translate(
            $this->chartWidth / 2,
            $this->chartHeight / 2
        );

        $this->draw->pathStart();
        $this->draw->pathMoveToAbsolute($positions[0][0], $positions[0][4]);


        //Scale that by the 'value' of each point aka the distance from the chart's centre.

        //Also scale it by how rounded you want the chart.

        for ($i=0 ; $i<$numberOfPoints ; $i++) {
            list($nextPositionX, $nextPositionY) = $positions[($i + 1) % $numberOfPoints];

            list($controlPoint1X, $controlPoint1Y) = 
                $this->getControlPoint(
                    $positions[$i],
                    $tangents[$i],
                    1,
                    $roundness
                );

            list($controlPoint2X, $controlPoint2Y) =
                $this->getControlPoint(
                    $positions[($i + 1) % $numberOfPoints],
                    $tangents[($i + 1) % $numberOfPoints],
                    -1,
                    $roundness
                );

            $this->draw->pathCurveToAbsolute(
                $controlPoint1X, $controlPoint1Y,
                $controlPoint2X, $controlPoint2Y,
                $nextPositionX, $nextPositionY
            );
        }

        $this->draw->pathClose();
        $this->draw->pathFinish();
    }
}

function getValues() {

    $coordinates_1 = [
        145,
        80,
        125,
        165,
        145
    ];

    return $coordinates_1;
}

$spiderChart = new SpiderChart();

$spiderChart->drawChartBackground();

$points = getValues();

//$spiderChart->drawBlendedChart($points, 0.2);

$spiderChart->drawBezierChart($points, 0.5);


$image->drawImage($spiderChart->getDraw());

if (!debug) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo $image;
}
```

Comment: the function pathMoveToAbsolute is making this bizar drawing, removing this gives the 2e result. I will wait for your example :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the image:

[image: http://downloads.gdwebs.nl/failed-bezier.png]

looks so crazy is that there is a [bug in ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26655) when you use pathCurveToQuadraticBezierSmoothAbsolute as the first element on a path.

It should be fixed in the next release of ImageMagick.